# On Window Resize Event

Tags: windows, vba, excel, winapi, vb6

## The Problem

Call a procedure whenever the **Main Excel Window** is resized.

### First attempt:

```
Sub Workbook_WindowResize(ByVal Wn As Window)
    Debug.Print Wn.Width & "x" & Wn.Height
End Sub
```

**Results:**

The sub routine is called whenever the 'inner' workbook window is resized but not when the application window is resized. I.E. occcurs on resize of the Multiple Document Interface child containing the application instance.

### Second attempt

```
Dim WithEvents App As Application
Private Sub App_WindowResize(ByVal Wb As Workbook, ByVal Wn As Window)
    Debug.Print Wn.Width & "x" & Wn.Height
End Sub
```

**Results:**

Oddly, the same thing that happened before occurs, which definitely surprised me. The event only occurs when the workbook window is resized instead of the application window.

For this reason I started looking into using the windows API.

There are many examples of setting SystemWide keyboard and mouse hooks using the windows APIs. This is along the same lines:

```
Public Enum enHookTypes
    WH_CALLWNDPROC = 4
    WH_CALLWNDPROCRET = 12
    WH_CBT = 5
    WH_DEBUG = 9
    WH_FOREGROUNDIDLE = 11
    WH_GETMESSAGE = 3
    WH_HARDWARE = 8
    WH_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 1
    WH_JOURNALRECORD = 0
    WH_MOUSE = 7
    WH_MSGFILTER = (-1)
    WH_SHELL = 10
    WH_SYSMSGFILTER = 6
    WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13
    WH_MOUSE_LL = 14
    WH_KEYBOARD = 2
 End Enum

Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As LongPtr, ByVal lpfn As Long, ByVal hMod As Long, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetLastError Lib "kernel32" () As Long

'Ensure that your hook procedure does not interfere with the normal operation of other hook procedures
Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long, ByVal ncode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Public hndl As Long

Sub HookWindow()
    hndl = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, AddressOf measureWindow, Application.Hinstance, 0&)
    Debug.Print hndl & "~~" & GetLastError()
End Sub

Sub unhookWindow()
    ret = UnhookWindowsHookEx(hndl)
    Debug.Print ret
End Sub

Public Sub measureWindow(code As Long, wParam As Long, lParam As Long)
    If code > 0 Then
        Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Width & "x" & ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Height
    Else
        ret = CallNextHookEx(measureWindow, code, wParam, lParam)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Results:**

If I replace the `WH_CALLWNDPROC` in:

```
hndl = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, AddressOf measureWindow, Application.Hinstance, 0&)
```

with `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` the sub-routine is called whenever a key is pressed. Similarly, if I replace it with `WH_MOUSE_LL` the sub-routine is called whenever the mouse is moved or a mouse button pressed.

The problem is that when I try to hook the sub-routine to `WH_CALLWNDPROC` nothing happens?

### Why?

I'm still not sure, but the same is true for all ENUMS in `enHookTypes` except `WH_MOUSE_LL` and `WH_KEYBOARD_LL`. Looking through the WinAPI documentation I read that you can use `GetLastError` from Kernel32.dll do get some indication of why the operation failed.

The error numbers I have got so far are (in decimal) `error 5` (for JOURNAL hooks) and `error 1428` for the rest.

Ultimately this also failed.

Comment: The error code `1428` translates to *"Cannot set nonlocal hook without a module handle."* This is to be expected. You are installing a global hook, but specify the module handle of an arbitrary module (the application's main module in this case). This should be the module that implements the hook procedure. You would either need to place your hook procedure in a DLL, and pass that module handle, or install a local (thread) hook instead. It's not clear why you set out to install a global hook to begin with.

Comment: ^^^That.  If all you need to do is catch window messages, [SetWindowLongPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898(v=vs.85).aspx) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @IInspectable I was setting a global hook because I figured that would be the only way to grab events occurring on the Excel Application Window itself.

Comment: @Comintern How does SetWindowLongPtr help? I need to establish a hook, not set a window property. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You use SetWindowLongPtr to set a callback to your own WndProc (see the GWLP_WNDPROC). That lets you respond to window messages for a specific window.  You're basically injecting yourself into the Excel window's message pump.

Comment: @Comintern: That's not how you subclass a window in this millennium. See [Subclassing Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773183.aspx) for information.

Comment: @IInspectable - VBA isn't a product of this millennium. Creating a `SUBCLASSPROC` is (to put it mildly) non-trivial.

Comment: @Comintern: Prior to learning, how to tie my shoes, tying shoes appeared to be non-trivial to me as well. I'm not sure what you are trying to say here, but any supported version of Excel is a product of this millennium, hosting arbitrary extensions outside your control. Those extensions may just decide to subclass the application window as well. At that point you need to use a subclassing approach, that is capable of cooperation.

Comment: @Comintern So would it be something like this: `SetWindowLong Application.hWnd, GWLP_WNDPROC, DWLP_USER, AddressOf measureWindow` ?

Comment: There are only 3 parameters, and DWLP_USER is for dialog boxes. [There's an example here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/general-excel-discussion-other-questions/420673-challenging-problem-how-make-excel-subclassing-safe-stable.html).

Comment: Hm... The example is a great demonstration. One question though, what message is sent to the window when it is resized? I assumed it might be EM_REQUESTRESIZE however with the code provided this seems to do nothing while the window is being resized...? I assume I have the incorrect message

Comment: `EM_REQUESTRESIZE` is sent to a Rich Edit Control. A regular window receives `WM_SIZE`, `WM_SIZING`, `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`, plus a handful of other messages when it is resized. They are used a slightly different times, and for different purposes. You'll have to look them up to see, which one you need to handle. When in doubt, use a tool like Spy++ to observe window messages being generated in response to resizing a window.

Comment: What version? In Excel 2016 the approach with the `Application` wrapper class works fine and triggers on "main window resize".

Comment: @RikSportel Excel 2010. Cool to hear it works in 2016 though :)

Comment: @Sancarn 2016 by default opens a new window for each opened Workbook, whereas up until 2010 you have these minimizable windows within the Application Window. Currently I don't have a 2010 installation at hand though, so I can't provide an actual answer. Maybe later :)

Comment: > 2016 by default opens a new window for each opened Workbook. Honestly I think that is a really good change... Subwindow system/MDI is very annoying to use....

Comment: It's still the same Application instance, which is nice. It's possible to instantiate a new app as well, but there's no visual difference when you make the new app visible.

Answer (score 1):

Application.Windows is a collection of window objects of Worbooks opened within the Application. The WindowResize event is raised when a **non-maximized** window changes size. The Workbook_WindowResize(ByVal Wn As Window) is exposed within the workbook object itself. The Application_WindowResize(ByVal Wb as Workbook, ByVal Wn As Window) event has to do with ANY/ALL of the workbooks within the Application when a non-maximized workbook's window changes size. Hence the difference in references passed in by the events. It is just a Window in the first case, of the workbook that raised the event, within the workbook object, and there is no question here which window it is (it's the "Me" workbook's window). It is both the Workbook and that workbook's window when it is raised at the Application level since the workbook the event relates to needs identification :) And no, Excel does not have a "Resize" event for the App window itself and you would need to go to APIs for that.

With the later Excel versions (past the 2010), there is ONE workbook per Excel Application window, the workbook's window is always maximized in the old sense, and both Workbook and Application events refer to the same workbook and would work just as you would want them to.

Answer (score -1):

Solution , create a timer event that checks and compares the width every few seconds...

```
Sub my_ONTIME()
    application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:2"), "my_TIMEREVENT"
End Sub
Sub my_TIMEREVENT()
    If application.Width <> EWIDTHR Then ESCREENRESIZE
    my_ONTIME
End Sub
Sub ESCREENRESIZE()
    Dim EWIDTH As Single
    Dim ESIDE As Single
    Dim EMID As Single
    EWIDTH = application.Width
    EWIDTHR = EWIDTH
    If EWIDTH < 500 Then
        EWIDTH = 500
        application.Width = 500
    End If
    EMID = 80 * 5.41
    ESIDE = ((EWIDTH - EMID) / 2) / 5.41
    Sheet1.Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = ESIDE
    Sheet1.Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = ESIDE
End Sub
```